# Rails: routing update error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am getting a routing error: No route matches "/deccom_tasks/update/1" with {:method=>:put}

I'm not sure why I am getting a routing error for a route that usually works.

Route:

```
 map.resources :decom_tasks, :collection => {:sort => :post, :deactivate_task => :get,  :reactivate_task => :get}
```

Controller:

```
 def update
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.update_attributes(params[:task])
        format.html { redirect_to(@task, :notice => 'Task was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @task.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: would it have something to do with the fact that 'Task' is a model, and then there is a Task controller, a decom_task controller, and a com_task controller?

Comment: your error says 'deccom' while your route says 'decom'

Comment: are you getting the error before or after the update. routes are usually like this `resource/1/update`, not `resource/update/1` not sure why it's like that

Comment: syntax error fail. Thanks. Would not have noticed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark Thomas was right, syntax error